# How to make toggle menu on bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-3

Hi all I am a new of bootstrap .I have problam with toggle menu when I scale broswer to small size it show the menu but when I click the toggle menu it not show the menu how can I do it ?

and this my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(function(){
      $('#slide-submenu').on('click',function() {             
            $(this).closest('.list-group').fadeOut('slide',function(){
              $('.mini-submenu').fadeIn();  
            });

          });

      $('.mini-submenu').on('click',function(){   
            $(this).next('.list-group').toggle('slide');
            $('.mini-submenu').hide();
      })
    })

    </script>
    <nav id="nav-menu" style="clear:both" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a id="hi" class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url().'./site/index' ?>">Home</a>
        </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul id="nav-menu-hi" class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=='burger'){echo "active";} ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'./site/burger' ?>">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=='promotion'){echo "active";} ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'./site/promotion' ?>">Promotion</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=='events'){echo "active";} ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'./site/events' ?>">Events</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=='contact'){echo "active";} ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'./site/contact' ?>">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=='about'){echo "active";} ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'./site/about' ?>">About Us</a></li>  
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the console for errors? Where do you add jQuery? If it's in the footer, you should add your script after it.